# Robocopy fails for folder with particular character in name

Tags: windows, unicode

I'm calling Windows' `robocopy` from Java to move some data around. An odd thing I noticed is it fails entirely if both of the following conditions are met:

- The destination is a symbolic link to a network share
- The source contains a folder with [`U+0250 LATIN SMALL LETTER TURNED A`](http://rishida.net/uniview/?charlist=%C9%90#title) in the name

Robocopy spits out error messages like the following: `2015/02/06 12:44:54 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Creating Destination Directory c:\mylink\test results\????????\
The system cannot find the file specified.`

(Use `mklink /D mylink \\your_network_share\name\here` from an elevated console to make a symbolic link)

My questions are:

- Why does this fail?
- How can I prevent this failure? (I cannot change/sanitize the input data.)
- Are there any other characters I should be worried about?

Comment: This is/was a [bug in java](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4947220). Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm using `java full version "1.8.0_20-b26"` but I have now seen this occur when calling `robocopy` straight from the command line.

Comment: At first glance, the most likely cause is that the target filesystem can't handle the character, rather than a problem with robocopy.  What happens if you do the same copy via Explorer?  Does the problem really only occur when the target is a symbolic link - what happens if you robocopy directly to the target UNC path?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, it really only occurs if both conditions are met. If I use the network path directly, the copy succeeds. If I use Windows Explorer, it succeeds. The only time it fails is if I use a symbolic link to a network path. It even works with a symbolic link to the local drive. I just find it rather odd that it doesn't work in this one combination.

Comment: IIRC, robocopy would usually overwrite a symlink rather than copying through it, so I suppose a bug in this edge case isn't *too* surprising.  It is odd that it only occurs for source directories containing a particular character though.  What happens if the symbolic link isn't the last element in the target path?  Have you tried using the `/b` option?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I've tried with the symlink not the last element, and got the same results. I haven't tried `/B`, as there was something on the web that had me shy away from that. I can't recall what it was at the moment, but they were concerned that it would not work in some cases. I'll give it a try next time I test this software.